# Python, how do i find files that end with a specific format in a folder

Tags: python

```
import shutil, os

path = 'C:\\Users\\cHaTrAp\Documents\\My Games\\KillingFloor2\\KFGame\\Cache\\*'

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.kfm' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    print(f)
```

I am trying to find a specific files in a folder that ends with .kfm so i can move them.
I am having problem to search multiple folder.

Comment: Use `endswith()` to check the file type: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_endswith.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give a you a list of files under the current directory tree, with the specified suffix.

```
from pathlib import Path

filelist = list( Path( '.' ).glob('**/*.kfm') )

print( filelist )
```

In the following, we go a step further.  We sort the filelist, and then loop over the files

```
from pathlib import Path

mysubdir = 'whatever'

pathlist = Path( mysubdir).glob('**/*.kfm')

filelist = sorted( [str(file) for file in pathlist] )

for file in filelist:
    print( file )
```

Answer (score 2):

you are doing everything fine but your path is wrong.

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\cHaTrAp\Documents\\My Games\\KillingFloor2\\KFGame\\Cache\\*'
```

won't work

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\cHaTrAp\Documents\\My Games\\KillingFloor2\\KFGame\\Cache'
```

the * is not needed.

Also like in the comment you should use endswith to avoid files that has '.kfm' in their name instead as file extension.

Answer (score 0):

here First thing your path is wrong 
it should be

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\cHaTrAp\Documents\\My Games\\KillingFloor2\\KFGame\\Cache'
```

then to get files with .kfm extention you can also use below code

```
import os
files = os.listdir(path)
kfm_files=[f for f in files if '.kfm' in f]
```